# Having a issue with generating wordcloud out of dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm doing an online course learning Python, and i'm stuck with an assignment.
The task is creating an dictionary, filter out punctuations and common words and finally generate the wordcloud. This is what I got:

```py
def calculate_frequencies(file_contents):
    # Here is a list of punctuations and uninteresting words you can use to process your text

    punctuations = '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~'''
    uninteresting_words = ["the", "a", "to", "if", "is", "it", "of", "and", "or", "an", "as", "i", "me", "my", \
    "we", "our", "ours", "you", "your", "yours", "he", "she", "him", "his", "her", "hers", "its", "they", "them", \
    "their", "what", "which", "who", "whom", "this", "that", "am", "are", "was", "were", "be", "been", "being", \
    "have", "has", "had", "do", "does", "did", "but", "at", "by", "with", "from", "here", "when", "where", "how", \
    "all", "any", "both", "each", "few", "more", "some", "such", "no", "nor", "too", "very", "can", "will", "just"]

    boek = {}

    for word in file_contents.split():
        if word != uninteresting_words and word.isalpha():
            if word not in boek:
                boek[word] = 0
            boek[word] += 1
    #wordcloud
    cloud = wordcloud.WordCloud()
    cloud.generate_from_frequencies(boek.keys)
    return cloud.to_array()
```

This returns no errors. The cell which should generate the worldcloud however does:

```
myimage = calculate_frequencies(file_contents)
plt.imshow(myimage, interpolation = 'nearest')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-fd0f708f372c> in <module>
      1 # Display your wordcloud image
      2 
----> 3 myimage = calculate_frequencies(file_contents)
      4 plt.imshow(myimage, interpolation = 'nearest')
      5 plt.axis('off')

<ipython-input-61-a23e5e09adaa> in calculate_frequencies(file_contents)
     20 
     21     #wordcloud
---> 22     cloud = wordcloud.WordCloud()
     23     cloud.generate_from_frequencies(boek.keys)
     24     return cloud.to_array()

NameError: name 'wordcloud' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong and more importantly why? Many thanks for the help!

Comment: install `wordcloud` and import it in your file

Comment: I was going to say the same thing @sandeshdaundkar

Comment: @user3479780 yes that's the issue as can be seen from the code. :) great

Comment: only thing is, there should be an import error, which is not shown above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting an error is because you have not defined 'wordcloud' anywhere in your program.

In the line your error is pointing to you have

```
cloud = wordcloud.WordCloud()
```

You have not defined the first 'wordcloud' (not to be confused with the WordCloud()). This either means you are trying to use something you haven't imported or you forgot to define this earlier in your program.

Comment: You were right! I didn't rerun the cell importing wordcloud.